# Get list of test classes to be executed in JUnit 5

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit5

I have a test in my suite that requires a specific type of log to be in Azure's OMS resource. My approach is to insert these logs at the very beginning of my test run, before any tests have been executed, and to run the specific test fixture that needs them last. I do this because the SLA for OMS is not reliable. Logs do not appear instantly in log analytics, they take a few minutes to propagate.

My question is: is it possible to peek into the TestPlan object to see the list of classes to be run? I do not need to do this OMS log injection if I am not running the fixture that needs it (example: running a subset of the entire suite, debugging a single test, etc...). The entire test suite is run using the `mvn clean install` command, and I frequently execute and debug single tests using the built in JUnit5 runner in intellij

Comment: You don't simply run: "mvn clean install" in 2020!

Comment: I doubt that I understand your problem? Can you explain more in detail? If I correctly see one of your tests is environment specific/agnostic which means it is not a unit test. Sounds really like an integration test to me? Maybe I'm wrong ...

Comment: That is correct. This is not a unit test. This is integration level

Comment: So this means you should name it accordingly which means `*IT.java` and execute it via maven-failsafe-plugin via `mvn clean verify`....and you can ignore results in `*IT.java` if you like (see maven-failsafe-plugin:verify) ...the other question is: Does this test needs different dependencies than other unit tests? If yes you should move that to a different module so you have clean separation of concern...

Answer (score 1):

Launch the JUnit Platform in your own program to discover all test classes that Jupiter will execute. With this you get a handle to the test plan for each registered test engine:

```
LauncherDiscoveryRequest request = LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request()
    .selectors(
        selectPackage("com.example.mytests"),
        selectClass(MyTestClass.class)
    )
    .filters(
        includeClassNamePatterns(".*Tests")
    )
    .build();

Launcher launcher = LauncherFactory.create();

TestPlan testPlan = launcher.discover(request);

// Examine testPlan for Jupiter-based test classes...
```

See https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#launcher-api-discovery for details.

No, there's no Maven plugin that supports a dry-run mode.

Comment: I would like to get around doing this if possible. It will work for maven, but will be a headache for IDE usage

Comment: Then you should open an issue via the YouTrack system for IntelliJ IDEA. They could implement such a "dry-run" ... methinks.